# ¿Como hacer que scritps de base de datos con MySQL, para una aplicacion de escritorio?(sin necesidad de tener instalado mysql)

Tags: java-swing, mysql-workbench

estoy desarollando una aplicacion de escritorio con neatbeans 8.1, XAMPP y MYSQL Workbench, y lo que requiero es que mi usuario final no tenga que instalar MYSQL,ya que tengo el sql con los datos que extrae mi aplicacion.

Comment: Si es un cliente que se va a conectar a un servidor de DB que ya está en la red, no tienes que tener instalado MySQL, pero probablemente si requieras la instalación del cliente de la DB.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podes explicar mejor tu escenario?

Comment: Gracias por responder. @jachguate el detalle que el usuario no requiere que este en un servidor de base de datos, lo quiere local pero el solo quiere abrir la aplicacion y ahi hacer las correspondientes acciones.

Comment: MySQL es una base de datos que generalmente se utiliza como cliente servidor, hay una opción _embedded_, que según recuerdo, es de pago, pero sería una opción a seguir, y de esta manera el _motor_ de la base de datos reside _incrustado_ dentro de tu aplicación. Más info: https://www.mysql.com/oem/

Comment: @Jachguache muchas gracias por tu ayuda. checare esa opcion